# iOS: Hide all lines for specific section in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have UITableView with two sections, and I want the first section to appear without lines.

is it possible to hide all lines (top and bottom lines and cell separators) for only one section ?

Comment: which top and bottom lines ? if for section then yes and i don't think u would be able to apply different cell separator to different sections as it is property of the tableview.

Comment: each section in Grouped TableView has upper and lower lines, and they are not affected by 'separatorInset' property of the UITableViewCell.  I can hide the lines between cells by modifying 'separatorInset' property, but I don't know how to hide the upper and bottom lines of the section. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `separatorStyle` is a property of `UITableView`, so there is no way to change it for specific sections / rows.

But it's not hard to implement yourself, with a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass